# My android app is crashing due to two empty edittext fields

Tags: android, mobile

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)

    {
        float Percentage, newPercentage = 0;
        int Number;
        EditText Total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText Done = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        float num1 = Float.parseFloat(Total.getText().toString());
        float num2 = Float.parseFloat(Done.getText().toString());




        Percentage = (num2 / num1) * 100;
}
}
```

Above is my code, when I leave any one of them empty, it crashes.How to get over it.

Comment: post your full code

Comment: You should handle NumberParseException, in your case if you pass empty string to parseFloat() function, there will be a chance for exception.

Comment: Yes, it worked with NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using Try...Catch

```
 float num1 = 0.00f;
 float num2 = 0.00f;

try {
   num1 = Float.parseFloat(Total.getText().toString());
   num2 = Float.parseFloat(Done.getText().toString());
   Percentage = (num2 / num1) * 100;
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    //Handle Non Float Exception
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid input !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether user has entered anything or not and then parse your value:

```
if(!Total.getText().toString().matches(""))
    float num1 = Float.parseFloat(Total.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
if(!Total.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&!Done.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                 float num1 = Float.parseFloat(Total.getText().toString());
                float num2 = Float.parseFloat(Done.getText().toString());

             Percentage = (num2 / num1) * 100;}
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply condition if EditText is not empty then your code is run like that

```
            float Percentage, newPercentage = 0;
            int Number;
            EditText Total = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            EditText Done = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

            String total=Total.getText().toString();
            String done=Done.getText().toString();

            if (!total.isEmpty() && !done.isEmpty()) {

                float num1 = Float.parseFloat(Total.getText().toString());
                float num2 = Float.parseFloat(Done.getText().toString());


                Percentage = (num2 / num1) * 100;
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(OpenFile.this, "Fill values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Check whether you find editText properly or not 
After that also check isEmpty condition  for avoiding NullPointer Exception

```
if (!editText1.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !editText2.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    float num1 = Float.parseFloat(Total.getText().toString());
    float num2 = Float.parseFloat(Done.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check for empty text, if not empty than perform calculation

```html
  if(!Total.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !Done.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                 float num1 = Float.parseFloat(Total.getText().toString());
                float num2 = Float.parseFloat(Done.getText().toString());

             Percentage = (num2 / num1) * 100;}
            }
        });
```